# Find X value of a circle center

Tags: c#, trigonometry

Is there a simple c# code to find the `X` value of a circle center if I have the following:

1. `X & Y` of two points on the circle;
2. Radius;
3. `Y` value of the center point.

This should leave only one variable `Xc`at the circle equations:

```
(Xp1-Xc)^2 + (Yp1-Yc)^2 = r^2
(Xp2-Xc)^2 + (Yp2-Yc)^2 = r^2
```

[image]

Comment: Start with how "you" as a human would find those things, and ask the computer to do the same

Comment: With the given parameters I would assume there will be 2 possible center points

Comment: Define the required variables and assign the given values. Make `Xc` the subject of the equation and print out the answer.

Comment: Create a variable for each of known values and write the formula in code. Hint Math.Pow

Comment: @Jerodev You are right, I have two points on the circle. I have edited the question.

Comment: do you need a formula. if possible post a picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: The best way of solving this is to use an isosceles triangle.  The two equal side of the triangle is the radius from the center of circle to each point on the circle.  Then solve as the intersection of two lines.  If you draw a line between the two points the center of the circle along a perpendicular to the line at the mid point.

Comment: @preciousbetine I have added a picture that shows the case. I know all the parameters except the vale of Xc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math and not about coding

Comment: @TaW Although it is about math, there should be a code to solve it...

Comment: do the lines pass through the center of the circle?

Comment: ... and what if both X and Y have the same x-coordinate? Which center will you take?

Comment: @preciousbetine These lines are not exist in the actual question, only the two points, Y value of the center, and the radius are there.